# Multiply two columns and put result in third column during insertion in mysql using stored procedure

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, insert

I want to do something like this:

```
Quantity   Price    Payment
1           12      12.00
```

Here's my code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `insertproducts`
(
    pname varchar(50), 
    pdesc varchar(50),
    psupp varchar(50),
    pdate date,
    pquant int,
    pprice double
)
begin
insert into products
(
    prodname,
    proddescription,
    prodsupplier,
    proddate,
    prodquantity,
    prodprice,
    prodpayment
) 
values 
(
    pname,
    pdesc,
    psupp,
    pdate,
    pquant,
    pprice,
    ppayment
) 
set prodpayment = pprice * prodquantity;
end
```

This is not working, any idea?

Comment: this is similar procedure with [scarface23](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2062096/scarface23). Anyway, do you have `Amount` column on the table?

Comment: yup I have ,actually it's not amount, it's payment column.

Comment: If you want to set `prodpayment` to `pprice*prodquantity`, why does the procedure have a `ppayment` parameter?

Comment: @eggyal: I've updated it man.

Comment: what are the columns that are set as unique on your table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what is `ppayment`? You can directly multiply the parameters,

```
insert into products
(
    prodname, 
    proddescription, 
    prodsupplier, 
    proddate, 
    prodquantity, 
    prodprice, 
    prodpayment
) 
values 
(
    pname, 
    pdesc, 
    psupp, 
    pdate, 
    pquant, 
    pprice, 
    pprice*prodquantity
)
```